# 3D charting in Flex (surface)

Tags: apache-flex, charts, 3d, geometry-surface

Do you have any recommendation for a free 3D charting library in Flex. To be more precise, I only need to draw surface (for now). Basically, I just need a chart that displays three axes (one should be timeline, and two should be linear axises) and the surface.

From what I have seen so far, two most popular free Flesh 3D libraries are Papervision3D and Away3D. Also, I've found one IBM library - ILOG Elixir that looks really nice, but it's proprietary (although, I haven't seen any surface examples for Elixir neither).

From what I have seen, Papervision3D and Away3D should do much more then 3D charting, but I haven't seen any examples on how to draw surfaces in any of them (except this line chart in 3D: http://www.insideria.com/2008/06/3d-charts-using-papervision3d.html).

So, if anyone has a link to a documentation or some examples that would be great. Also, I'm interested to hear your opinion and recommendations on this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check out [Defraga](http://www.degrafa.org/index.html)

Its an open source declarative graphics framework. It may not have the 3d Charting options but  its pretty useful in developing Rich user interfaces.

Comment: It looks interesting. Although, as you've pointed out, it doesn't have support for 3D charting.

Comment: I think the best approach may be a combination of Degrafa & Papervision 3D. I don't think there's much documentation out there, but the Papervision and Degrafa guys are usually very open to answering questions.

Comment: true..you can always make your own 3d charts using these frameworks else you have to pay for the license :)

Comment: Yeah, if nothing else helps I'll implement component myself. But I was kind of hoping that somebody has already done something similar, since this is something that's like a general problem (I presume that a lot of developers had a similar problem before).